# Circular dependency in code first approach of mvc

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have three tables:

```
Group, Contact and Address
```

**Group**

```
  GroupID (pk)              
  GName
```

**Contact**

```
 ContactID (pk)                                                                   
 GroupID (fk)   
 Name
```

**Address**

```
AddressID (pk)
GroupID   (fk) 
ContactID (fk)
```

I want to do follow using these three tables:

1. when I delete/Update group detail then the contacts and addresses must be deleted/updated.
2. when I delete/update contact detail, contact & address must be deleted/update.
3. I want to find group by an address (group which contains the address).

How to resolve it in code first approach in entity framework?

How to resolve it in database first approach in entity framework?

Finally;

I have problem to create these tables in `SQL` database. I'm having a cyclic dependency error.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the Cyclic dependency, its due to the foreign keys in place. So you should start by creating the `Group` table, then `Contact` and finally `Address` and in the same way,when deleting a row, you should start by the dependant table (Those which contains foreign keys)

And to answer to your questions;

1. Firstly, since only the `GroupID` is used in the other tables, you don't have to care for updates *(I don't think you'll update the ID though!)*. But to **delete**, you'll need to delete all the rows using the GroupID in `Address table` first. then all the rows in the `Contact table`. Only then, you may proceed to delete the row in your `Group table`.
2. To delete a Contact, you should proceed by deleting all the rows bearing the ContactID in the `Address table` first, then the `Contact table`.

3 to find the group containing your address;

```
Select G.GroupId, G.GName 
From   Group as G
Left outer join Address A
on A.GroupID    = G.GroupID   
Where A.AddressID = 'Your Address ID'
```